# Show application logo on application startup and authenticate user WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a working WPF application and now I want to add Roles/Permissions and Login functionality to it. I plan to authenticate user on the Application_startup event but while showing the login dialog here I want to show user a welcome type application startup window like we see when Microsoft office loads. Is there a built in way to design something like this or I should just design a new dialog for this? Also whats the best way to authenticate users in WPF?

Comment: Well you are asking two questions in one, in my opinion you should open two different questions. Anyway regarding the first, I understood you want to understand how to show a splash screen in a WPF application?

Comment: yup a splash screen is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About including a splash screen in a WPF application please read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc656886%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I did not know what this screen is called :) it is very easy thanks for the help :)